# Navigate to a specified path in cmd file

Tags: cmd

Now I am currently in C:\WINDOWS\system32>
I need to mention it in the cmd file
How can I navigate to a specific path in cmd file.
Please provide the lines.
@echo off
setlocal
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
cd "C:\hadoop-2.6.0-src"
 mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
pause
popd
This is my cmd file.The mvn command is not getting executed in the specified path. two separate command prompts is getting opened but it is not running and get closed immediately

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how to change current location? Just use cd command.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" pause This is my cmd file. i need to move to C:\hadoop-2.6.0-src this location automatically.

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in a comment as it becomes slightly illegible (unreadable). [Edit] your question rather.

Answer (score 0):

`PUSHD` Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the `POPD` command

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "C:\hadoop-2.6.0-src"
cd
pause
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
cd
pause
popd
```

Additional `cd` commands (without parameters) should display the current drive and directory.

[Read more](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

Comment: I have tried these lines but even then the command prompt is not getting navigated to the specified path. Please tell me some more options. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No error messages? E.g. `The system cannot find the path specified.` @HariniMuralidharan